# Dynamic window creation at run time - Drools Fusion 6 / Esper

Tags: dynamic, complex-event-processing, esper, sliding-window, drools-fusion

I need to achieve a dynamic sliding window of length (5) where I have incoming flight statuses from various flights coming into one stream.

Based on the flight_id property from various flights - dynamic windows of length 5 have to be created at run time and its average speed has to be maintained individually.

This example in Drools Fusion does not work when I insert multiple flights with different flight ids and speeds into it - http://books.google.co.in/books?id=trrfxX8JCisC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=flight+average+speed+example+drools+fusion&source=bl&ots=NpRv7D32Us&sig=6XbWtIQ2T1idGMQRU_hQZgmd8fc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RBAUU92yIsLkiAenFg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=flight%20average%20speed%20example%20drools%20fusion&f=false

The window gets reset when it detects a new flight id.

Please let me know if there is a solution for this in Drools Fusion or Esper or any other open source CEP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link does not work.

Can you perhaps clarify "dynamic windows" and "windows get reset"? It is not clear what that could mean.

In Esper I have found an example in the docs in "4.2.6.1. Distinct Events for the Initiating Condition" and rewrote this for you what may match the somewhat fuzzy requirements:

```
create context Flight initiated by distinct(flightId) FlightEVent 
  terminated after 5 seconds; // you don't mention when to throw a flight away
context Flight select avg(speed) from FlightEvent.win:length(5);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked in Esper using patterns. But what you've posted looks even simpler. We will try that out as well.